# PHP - How to execute a function stored in a variable?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, function, file

I need to output in style.css.php the values of 2 variables $style1 and $style2 both located in display.php

display.php ( I must not modify this file directly ):

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists( 'add_customizer_css' ) ) {

    function add_customizer_css() {

        $bgcolor = '#fff';
        $fontcolor = '#000';

        $style1 = '.some-class { background-color: ' . $bgcolor . ';}';
        $style2 = '.some-class { color: ' . $fontcolor . ';}';

        wp_add_inline_style( 'style1', $style1 ); // Unwanted line
        wp_add_inline_style( 'style2', $style2 ); // Unwanted line
    }
}
```

I'm not sure the following is the best way to achieve that...

style.css.php:

```
<?php

$display_php = file_get_contents( '../theme/inc/customizer/display.php' );

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/^<\?php/';
$patterns[1] = '/wp_add_inline_style\( \'style1\', \$style1 \);/';
$patterns[2] = '/wp_add_inline_style\( \'style2\', \$style2 \);/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';
$replacements[1] = 'echo $style1';
$replacements[2] = 'echo $style2';

$display_php = preg_replace( $patterns, $replacements, $display_php );

header( 'Content-type: text/css' );

include( '../theme/style.css' ); // Aditionnal CSS

// Here I need to output $style1 and $style2
```

So is it possible to execute add_customizer_css() which is stored in $display_php, this way, it can define and output $style1 and style2 ?

Comment: What if you include `display.php` in `style.css.php`?

Comment: In this case I'm not sure how could I modify display.php by replacing the 2 unwanted lines by echo $style*. Once included would  I be able to call add_customizer_css() and output $style1 and $style2 ?

Comment: After you include it you can call `add_customizer_css()`.  In order to understand the problem corectly I need to know what exactly is in $style*

Comment: $style* was my way to reference both $style1 and $style2. Both including string of CSS code with variables defining the dynamic CSS values. I guess that by including display.php, I can call add_customizer_css() without problem. But before to call it, how could I modify add_customizer_css() by replacing the 2 unwanted lines by echo $style1 and echo $style2 ?

Comment: EDIT: In the display.php excerpt, I clarified (and simplified) what exactly is in $style1 and $style2.

Comment: it is possible to run a function stored in a variable simply by adding the parenthesis to the variable like so : `$function_name()`

Comment: If [that's](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) what you speak about, I don't think it can help... The function I'd like to call ( add_customizer_css() ) is stored in $display_php with its definition. The value of $display_php is not the function name but the content of a file: display.php which contain that function and its definition.

Comment: It seems like the only way you can achieve what you are looking for is editing `display.php`. Are you sure you can't edit it?

Comment: Yep, `display.php` is a file of the parent theme on which my custom child theme depends. I could unhook  `add_customzer_css()` and hook my `custom_add_customizer_css()` instead or even overwrite this function but it makes me loose the flexibility I need... The only way I found so far is creating `third-file.php` with `file_put_contents( third-file.php, $display_php );` Then I `include third-file.php;` in `style.css.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. Take notice that this uses `eval()` and is usually not recommended. Search in Google about the risks of using `eval()`. I also use the [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/es/class.reflectionfunction.php).

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: text/css' );

include( '../theme/inc/customizer/display.php' );

$ref = new ReflectionFunction('add_customizer_css');
$start = $ref->getStartLine();
$end = $ref->getEndline();

$lines = file('../theme/inc/customizer/display.php');

$function = '';
for($i = $start; $i < $end - 1; $i++){
    if(strpos($lines[$i], 'wp_add_inline_style') === false){
        $function .= $lines[$i];
    }   
}
$function .= 'echo "$style1\n$style2\n";';
eval($function);

include('../theme/style.css'); // Aditionnal CSS
```